# Open UserForm upon selecting any cell in a table

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I am using the following code to open a userform upon cell selection in a table by user, where each table has 30 rows with multiple tables in one sheet. I will have to write 100s of lines again and again.

I know this is not an efficient way to do so. How do I make this code simpler and shorter without affecting functionality?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$D$31:$E$31" Then
 Open_Text_Form
End If

If Target.Address = "$D$32:$E$32" Then
 Open_Text_Form
End If

If Target.Address = "$D$33:$E$33" Then
 Open_Text_Form
End If

If Target.Address = "$D$34:$E$34" Then
 Open_Text_Form
End If

If Target.Address = "$D$35:$E$35" Then
 Open_Text_Form
End If

If Target.Address = "$D$36:$E$36" Then
 Open_Text_Form
End If

If Target.Address = "$D$37:$E$37" Then
 Open_Text_Form
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The section of Stack Overview entitled Code Review would be the best place to work on efficiencies.  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Intersect function to find if a range (cell) is inside of a given range. Without knowing how the data is setup in the sheet, I can't say what the best way to check is. If the multiple "tables" on your sheet are actually Excel tables, you can do something like this to have it check if you have clicked inside of one of them.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim tableRange As Range

For i = 1 To ListObjects.Count

    If i = 1 Then
        Set tableRange = ListObjects(i).DataBodyRange
    Else
        Set tableRange = Application.Union(tableRange, ListObjects(i).DataBodyRange)
    End If

Next

If tableRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, tableRange) Is Nothing Then
    Open_Text_Form
End If

End Sub
```

However if the "tables" in your sheet are just normal data ranges you could define them in a named range and all you would need to do is

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("MyNamedRange")) Is Nothing Then
    Open_Text_Form
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Dear Wedge, huge hug and many thanks for the assistance and yes, your second proposed solution worked for me and converted whole 35line code into 2-3 lines only! Yes, this is what I was requesting exactly! Many thanks again and it is really highly appreciated!